# how to copy one gpencil layer from one scene to another scene in the same blender file?

Tags: rendering

how to copy one gpencil layer from one scene to another scene in the same nlender file ?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

In 3d-view change mode to **Edit Strokes**:

[image]

Then select strokes (for example using <kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>C</kbd> or <kbd>B</kbd>), then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

Then move to different scene  create a new layer, set mode to  **Edit Strokes** and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>.

Comment: yes, that's what I did. But I wanted to copy a complete layer from one scene to another as a layer photoshop.